# Novice enquiry on using TryParse() properly

Tags: c#

I've just tried `TryParse`, and am new to C# and just trying to understand everything, and then hopefully best practices...

Syntactically this works:

```
double number = Double.Parse(C.ReadLine());
```

Does TryParse only return a boolean, true if parse succeeds?

When I do this:

```
double number;
bool b = Double.TryParse(C.ReadLine(), out number);
```

`number` is the parsed input, from `C.ReadLine()`, as expected, everything works. Is this how TryParse is normally used? Trying to be efficient, appreciate advice like [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/228/).

Any advice on approach welcome, plus info on online resources for Try(things).

Answer (score 4):

You use `TryParse` when it may fail, and you don't want your code to throw an exception.

For example

```
if (!Double.TryParse(someinput, out number))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please input a valid number");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Parse` will return the double value if it succeeds and throws an exception otherwise. TryParse will return a boolean value representing the success of the operation and if it does succeed, it fills in the parsed value in the `out` argument you pass to it. It will never throw an exception.

In general, you should use `TryParse` when you expect the input string to not be a valid number and you have the logic to handle it (and display an error message, for instance).

If you don't expect the input string to be anything except a valid double you should use `Parse`.

Answer (score 1):

The only differnce is that TryParse won't thow an exception if it can't parse the double.

This is handy when you want to assign a default value or ignore the value in your code

Example:

```
double number;
if (Double.TryParse(C.ReadLine(), out number))
{
    // this is a double so all good
}
else
{
  // not a valid double.
}
```

Example:

```
double number;
progressBar.Value = Double.TryParse(C.ReadLine(), out number) ? number : 4.0;
// If number is a valid double, set progressbar, esle set default value of 4.0
```

You also asked aboy `TyrParse` on `Enum`, this can be done like this

```
DayOfWeek fav;
if (Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>(Console.ReadLine(), out fav))
{
    // parsed
}
```

Comment: I've seen TryParse() used with a double, and I've seen Parse() used on an enum... I wanted to understand how I could build an enumTryParse...

Comment: The scenario is that the user is prompted to enter favourite day. TryParse returns a bool, so should be usable in an if condition, but I get an error when I do this

DayOfWeek fav;

if ((DayOfWeek)Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out fav))
            {

            }

the working Parse is declared in a try statement as follows

 fav = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse( typeof(DayOfWeek), Console.ReadLine());

I'm wondering how this should be translated to the TryParse() statement, assuming it's possible! Can't see how to make it syntactically valid...